# Reflection on enum extension method located in separate assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, extension-methods

Code I have:

```
public enum ActivityStatus
{
    All = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2
}

public static class MyClass
{
    public static string Test(this ActivityStatus _value) { return _value + "111"; } 
}
```

And `typeof(ActivityStatus).GetMethods()` doesn't contain Test method. I even tried to put everything in the same assembly, but still no success. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods are just static methods, compiler translates this call

```
yourEnum.Test();
```

to:

```
MyClass.Test(yourEnum);
```

So in order to get `Test` method info via reflection, you need to inspect `MyClass`, `ActivityStatus` is just a parameter there.

```
var testMethodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Test");
var firstParameter = testMethodInfo.GetParameters()[0];

Console.WriteLine (firstParameter.ParameterType + " " + firstParameter.Name);
```

prints:

```
ActivityStatus _value
```

If you want to get **all** extension methods for type in a particular assembly, you can use next code:

```
var extensionMethodsForActivityStatus = 
        typeof(ActivityStatus) //type from assembly to search
           .Assembly  //pick an assembly
           .GetTypes() //get all types there 
           .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods()) //get all methods for that type
           .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Any() &&
                       m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == typeof(ActivityStatus)) //check if first parameter is our enum
           .Where(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), true)); //check if the method is an extension method

foreach(var extensionMethod in extensionMethodsForActivityStatus)
    Console.WriteLine(extensionMethod.Name); //prints only Test
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect it to be there? The enum has no methods. The extension method is in class `MyClass`. The fact that you can call it with a different syntax so it looks just like a method of `ActivityStatus` is just syntactic sugar on top.

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMethods()
```

should return the method if you use the proper binding flags (public, static) .